# why "wash" and not "washed"?

Tags: tense, past-tense

> I helped my mother **wash** the dishes after dinner last night.

May I know last night is past, why *wash* is present?

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence the verb "wash" is short of its indefinite form "to wash," which does not have a tense, so it's not in the present tense.

> I helped my mother **to wash** the dishes after dinner last night.

"Help to do" is a double verb construction, in which the second verb is in the indefinite form ([PrimeGram](http://www.fe.hku.hk/telec/pgram/5-gr/e321-041.htm)). Other examples are "He tries to relax." and "She decided to write."

Comment: I helped my mother washed the dishes after dinner last nite.  May I know if I don't put 'to wash' can use washed?

Comment: No, you can't. Because you can't use two verbs one after another like that.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @mac_t13 In this construction, *help* is an auxiliary verb. Any verb following an auxiliary verb needs to be in the infinitive or bare infinitive (in this case, either *to wash* or just *wash*). If you add something between the two verbs, that can change. For instance: *I helped my mother* ***who washed*** *the dishes* or *I helped my mother* ***as she washed*** *the dishes*.

Comment: @JasonBassford are you sure "help" is an auxillary verb? I was thinking "help to wash" or "help washing" could be [a double verb construction](http://www.fe.hku.hk/telec/pgram/5-gr/e321-041.htm). Or this is called so only when the two verbs are next to each other?

Comment: @Jan Hmm. You could be right. I considered it to be the same as an auxiliary verb construction, but your terminology might be more accurate here. In either case, the second verb should be in the infinitive.